# Keeping csv order when creating pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file, from which I'm trying to create a spark streaming dataframe. The problem is, when printing the records I noticed they are in random order. Is there a way to keep the order of the original csv file when creating the stream?
I tried orderBy the Index field but got this error: ***pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Sorting is not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, unless it is on aggregated DataFrame/Dataset in Complete output mode;;***

I need the order because later, I'll be using a concept drift model that requires ordered data.

```
def f(row):
    print(row)

df = spark.readStream.format('csv').schema(csv_schema).option('header','true').option('delimiter',',').load('./Swat_dataset*.csv')
df_final = df.select("Index","MV301","AIT501","PIT503","Normal/Attack")
query = df_final.writeStream.outputMode("append").foreach(f).option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoints").start().awaitTermination()
```